# Which has better performance: SELECT...ENDSELECT (1 by 1) or SELECT...INTO TABLE / LOOP AT

Tags: abap

I have to read 10.000.000 records from a table.

Is it better:

- to read these records one by one using `SELECT ... ENDSELECT` (without internal table)
- or to read all of them at once using `SELECT ... INTO TABLE itab` and then LOOP through this internal table?

Comment: The wording is unprecise, you don't compare a database operation (SELECT) and a simple internal table iteration (LOOP AT), but the loading of the database in one operation or in several ones. The number of iterations (LOOP AT) will be globally the same for both cases.

Answer (score 6):

If all 10,000,000 entries fit into ABAP's main memory, you should select all of them with a single `SELECT ... INTO TABLE ...`, followed by a `LOOP`.

This reduces expensive database interaction to a minimum and will be fastest.

If the records don't fit into main memory, you need to retrieve them in packages. Check out the `PACKAGE SIZE` addition of the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: How do you know whether it fits or not? The question is theoretical/opinion-based because I would always suggest to do it in packages although the performance "could" be slower :)

Comment: The question whether the data fits is valid for all selects, but still most are done in one step, not in packages. We usually estimate the record count and size and validate it against the assumed system setup (esp. main memory) to decide whether to add packaging. But you are right, ~10M select is for sure a good candidate for "let's add packaging to be on the safe side..." Anything broader than a single-column GUID list will likely run out of memory. :-)

Comment: If you need to SELECT millions of rows, probably your architecture is the main problem, and most likely you need a GROUP BY or similar thing

Answer (score 5):

## They have about the same speed

Contrary to popular belief, `SELECT ... ENDSELECT` does not fetch the rows one-by-one, so its performance is not *much* worse than `SELECT ... INTO TABLE`. See the [explanation here](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/09/21/selectinto-table-faster-than-selectendselect-the-real-reason/).

### The big problem with `SELECT ... ENDSELECT` is that it prevents *other* performance improvements

Consider this coding:

```
SELECT matnr FROM mara
    INTO lv_matnr WHERE (...).
  SELECT SINGLE ebeln
      FROM ekpo 
      INTO lv_ebeln 
      WHERE matnr = lv_matnr.
  SELECT SINGLE zfield
      FROM ztable 
      INTO lv_zfield 
      WHERE matnr = lv_matnr.
  ...
ENDSELECT.
```

Most of the time will be spent with the SELECT SINGLEs on table `ekpo` and `ztable`, and often the solution for this is using `FOR ALL ENTRIES`<sup>1</sup>, however you need an internal table for that.
So it has to be converted into a `SELECT ... INTO TABLE` anyway:

```
SELECT matnr FROM mara
    INTO TABLE lt_matnr WHERE (...).
IF lt_mara IS NOT INITIAL.
  SELECT matnr, ebeln FROM ekpo
      INTO TABLE @lt_ekpo          "make it SORTED by matnr"
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_matnr
      WHERE matnr = @table_line.
  SELECT matnr, zfield FROM ztable
      INTO TABLE @lt_ztable        "make it SORTED by matnr"
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_matnr
      WHERE matnr = @table_line.
ENDIF. 
LOOP AT lt_matnr ASSIGNING <fs_mara>.
  READ TABLE lt_ekpo ASSIGNING <fs_ekpo>
      WITH KEY matnr = <fs_matnr>.
  READ TABLE lt_ztable ASSIGNING <fs_ztable>
      WITH KEY matnr = <fs_matnr>.
  ...
ENDLOOP.
```

You *should* avoid `SELECT ... ENDSELECT`, not because of its own performance, but to make other improvements easier.

---

1. You should use JOINs whenever you can instead of `FOR ALL ENTRIES`

Comment: I agree with the first statement about approximately the same speed, but not with the second one ("the big problem") as you make guesses about how the programs would use SELECT...ENDSELECT and you generalize. In your example, you may improve with a join without changing anything in the logic. Or a package size can be added as an intermediate solution. Note that `FOR ALL ENTRIES` is becoming more and more obsolete nowadays, joins and temporary tables are to be preferred.

Comment: @SandraRossi, you are right, _if_ you can use a JOIN, you should pick that over `FOR ALL ENTRIES`. However, quite often the driver table comes from a standard function call, an in those cases you do not have that luxury.